# Bootstrap Datepicker disabling future dates correctly but allows me to key in future dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I have implemented Bootstrap Datepicker in one of my MVC forms. Here in the code below, the TextBox is bound to a ViewModel property of type string (and not date).

While the calendar is correctly disabling all days beyond the max day of today, it is still allowing me to 'key in' a future date though.

Am I supposed to handle that in my ViewModel (data annotation) side or am I missing anything on the Javascript side of things setting the control up?

Thanks!

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndOfWeek, new { @id = "txtEndOfWeek", @class = "text - primary datepicker" })

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,       
        firstDay: 1,
        maxDate: '+0d',
    });
```

Comment: Datepickers don't usually apply validation to manually-entered input values. You'll have to do that in your app.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for confirming.